# how to access grub menu when it is locked with a password

Tags: centos, grub2, password

I am running a CentOS-7 virtual machine and I have the task of recovering the root password of the system. But the GRUB menu is locked with Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2. Therefore I cannot just press 'e' at the grub menu.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? I have no clue where to  start. Google searches only bring up people talking about pressing 'e' at the GRUB menu which isn't possible here.

Comment: Where is this VM running? Is this on your own box (eg running Oracle Virtual box)? or is this running in the cloud (eg aws)?  Your easiest way in (if it's not encrypted) might be to reset the root password by accessing the VM image without booting. Or if it's aws, you may be able to get a root console through the aws console.

Comment: my VM is running on vmware workstation

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Download the [Super Grub2 Disk ISO](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/) and insert
the image into your virtual optical drive and boot from it. 
Choose "Detect and show boot methods" from the menu; Super Grub2 should find your `grub.cfg` and add the entries to the list of 
boot options and bypass the password protection. Find the menu entry (scroll a bit down) and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit it.

Follow the instructions on the CentOS wiki page [Resetting a Forgotten Root Password](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/ResetRootPassword) (which links to the RedHat [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-terminal_menu_editing_during_boot#sec-Recovering_Root_Password)).